# Is there a way to optimise the processed CSS with SASS

Tags: css, ruby, sass

I have files `normalise.scss` and `base.scss`. I am adding styles to the `h` tags in both files. In the compiled CSS file, they are being added in two separate places like this:

```
/* set in the base */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 font-family: Times;
}

/* set in the normalise */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

Is there a ruby gem or utility that combines all of these into one declaration? i.e

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 font-family: Times;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: No, there is no such gem. It couldn't work. You can't move the rules unless there is literally nothing between them, or you change their precedence.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? For efficiency? I don't think it changes that much. Rather than doing it, setting the compile mode to compact would be more meaningful. If it is for debugging CSS, then Google Chrome developer's tool would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps you. Its a for loop of sass.

```
%heading{
   /*your css*/
}

@for $i from 1 through 6 {
  .h#{$i} { @extend heading; }
}
```